# Cannot add UILable to UITableViewCell in IOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, ios7, uilabel

Searching gave me nothing on the problem, so I decided to ask a question providing some code.
I need to add an UILabel to table view cell.
Here's initiating the cell:

```
UITableViewCell *cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellId];
```

Then, depending on some other parameters, one of the cell shall contain uiswitch and uilabel:

```
    titleText = @"Some title";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm";
    detailText = [formatter stringFromDate:_someDate];

    UISwitch *reminderSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 5, 60, 20)];
    IF_IOS6
    reminderSwitch.frameX = 175;

    reminderSwitch.on = NO;
    [reminderSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(reminderSwitchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [reminderSwitch setOnTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:78/255.0 green:169.0/255.0 blue:224/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

     if (/*Some Condition*/)
     {
        UILabel *detail = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 45, 150, 12)];
        IF_IOS6 
        detail.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20);

        detail.text = detailText;
        detail.font = cell.detailTextLabel.font;
        detail.textColor = cell.detailTextLabel.textColor;
        detail.hidden = NO;
        [cell addSubview:detail];
     }
     detailText = nil;

     [cell addSubview:reminderSwitch];
}
```

This code works well in IOS7.
This code does not work in IOS6. Please, show me where I have made a mistake.
Thank you in advance.

P.S. I just cannot create a new class for this kind of cell. And similar code (almost same) works well in IOS6 in some other controller using the same kind of UITableViewCell.

Comment: @evgeniy- is it entering in if condition in ios6 and what is the condition

Comment: why are you creating a custom label. you should use the default one of tableviewcell. simple "cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"your text"".

Comment: @evgeniy - Like Vivek said, Is it entering the IF_IOS6 condition? If yes, check if it is initialised or nil?

Comment: Yes, it enters all conditions. I cannot use cell.detailTextLabel because I need to move this label to custom position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
detail.font = cell.detailTextLabel.font;
```

To

```
detail.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
```

On iOS6 cell's text label has font with 0 px font size

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was in the font, indeed!